# Using Pug & HTML with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

I am creating a data dashboard that pulls data from a database and displays the data across a number of tabs, using NodeJS and PUG as the templating engine.

I am having no issues directly with using PUG, I quite enjoyed learning to use it and enjoy the easy-to-learn syntax. However, now I am starting to design an Admin back-end section which will contain a number of validated forms for manual data imports.

My question is, for these back-end forms which would not be accessed as much as the front-end dashboard and would also be heavily validated, would it be more efficient to resort to using HTML for these forms.
I'm not sure whether PUG would be the most efficient for creating these forms and as the back-end is not performance dependent, would using PUG have any other impacts?

TLDR: Would it make sense to use PUG for the front-end of a data dashboard whilst resorting to HTML for back-end forms.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi J_C, regarding my experience, I can't see any reason not to use jade/pug for your back-office too. Do you have more specific questions about it ?

Comment: Hi and thanks for taking the time to respond, I am a lot more experienced in HTML compared with PUG and therefore would be more comfortable creating forms w/ validation in html, if this causes no issues, however if this is just as achievable and simple in PUG it may be an idea to not mix them together.

Comment: The more you work with Pug, the more you'll appreciate its efficiencies over HTML. And the better you'll get at it. I can't think of any application where I'd rather use vanilla HTML over Pug.